# Cannot receive cookies on backend

Tags: javascript, express, web, cookies, server

Hello SO,

My server uses Node.js and Express. I have properly set up `cookie-parser` and `body-parser` and I can receive and send cookies most of the time.

So, my app is very basic actually.

1. Login page is presented.
2. Ajax request to `seslogin` with `idToken and csrfToken`.
3. Backend receives this tokens and *can read cookies from `req`*.
4. Creates session cookie and sends it to client.
5. Client redirects to `/profile` with `window.location.assign('profile')`
6. **Normally** backend reads session cookie, verify it and present a UI.

In my **app.ts**, I can receive cookies perfectly in this part. I'm calling `seslogin` with an Ajax request on my client script.

```js
app.post('/seslogin', function (req, res) {
    const idToken = req.body.idToken.toString();
    const csrfToken = req.body.csrfToken.toString();

    console.info('[SESLOGIN] Cookies: ', req.cookies);
    console.info('[SESLOGIN] Session Cookie: ', req.cookies.session);

    if (!req.cookies || csrfToken !== req.cookies.csrfToken) {
        res.status(401).send('UNAUTHORIZED REQUEST!');
        return;
    }
    const expiresIn = 60 * 60 * 24 * 5 * 1000;
    if (new Date().getTime() / 1000 - decodedClaims.auth_time < 5 * 60) {
            return admin.auth().createSessionCookie(idToken, { expiresIn: expiresIn });
        }
        throw new Error('UNAUTHORIZED REQUEST!');
    })
        .then(function (sessionCookie) {
            const options = { maxAge: expiresIn, httpOnly: true, secure: true };
            res.cookie('session', sessionCookie, options);
            res.end(JSON.stringify({ status: 'success' }));
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            res.status(401).send('UNAUTHORIZED REQUEST!');
        });
});
```

However, very interestingly in this part cookies are undefined

```js
app.get('/profile', function (req, res) {
    // Get session cookie.
    const sessionCookie = req.cookies.session || '';

    console.info('[PROFILE] Cookies: ', req.cookies);
    console.info('[PROFILE] Session Cookie: ', req.cookies.session);

    admin.auth().verifySessionCookie(sessionCookie, true)
    .then(function (decodedClaims) {
        // Serve content for signed in user.
        return serveContentForUser('/profile', req, res, decodedClaims);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        // Force user to login.
        console.error(new Error(error));
        //res.redirect('/login');
        res.redirect('/');
    });
});
```

client.js (Request)

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
    user.getIdToken().then(function (idToken) {
        var csrfToken = getCookie('csrfToken')
        return postIdTokenToSessionLogin('/seslogin', idToken, csrfToken)
            .then(function () {
                // Redirect to profile on success.
                window.location.assign('/profile');
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                window.location.assign('/login');
            });
    });
});
```

/profile request headers (on Chrome)

[image: /profile request headers]

Comment: Where are you actually setting the cookies? Can you show us the app setup. If cookies aren't being sent to `/profile`, perhaps the cookies that _were_ set are limited to a subpath only.

Comment: @prasanthv I have updated the question. I'm setting the cookie at the end of `/seslogin` method. Also I want to point out that I can see my cookies on `/profile` request headers in Chrome's developer tools.

Comment: Does Request contain `Cookie` header?

Comment: Is it a CORS request?  [withCredentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials)

Comment: @Buggy I have updated the question

Comment: @Buggy no no, it's a simple redirect.

Comment: `// Cookies that have not been signed . 
  console.log('Cookies: ', req.cookies) . 

  // Cookies that have been signed . 
  console.log('Signed Cookies: ', req.signedCookies)`
[cookie-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser)

Comment: @Buggy both of them are empty

Comment: @Buggy even weirder is `req.headers` doesn't contain cookies but chrome developer tools says it is

Comment: it is possible to do common request (not ajax) and check cookie again?

Comment: @Buggy I'm redirecting to `/profile` on auth success. How can I do a redirect with request? (I've updated client.js)

Comment: In chrome inspector, does the cookie you see have a path set?

Comment: @prasanthv no, it doesn't have any